# What finite groups can appear as collections of automorphisms of some field? Proof verification

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

1. What finite groups G can appear as collections of automorphisms of some field? More precisely, for which G does there exist a field F such that G is a subgroup of the automorphism group of F?
2. What finite groups G can occur as collections of automorphisms of some finite field F?

Here are my proof ideas

1. Recall that every finite group G is a subgroup of $S_n$, where n is the order of G. We claim that every finite group can appear as a collection of automorphisms of some field.

Let G be a group of order n. Then there exists a polynomial p(x) in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ such that the splitting field for p(x), L, has Galois group $S_n$. Then corresponding to every subgroup H of $S_n$ is a fixed field $L^H$ and H is the Galois group of $L^H$. Therefore G is the Galois group of its fixed field $L^G$. Note that the Galois group is a group of automorphisms and therefore G is the collection of automorphisms of $L^G$.

2. We claim that every finite cyclic group can occur as collections of automorphisms of some finite field.

Consider the cyclic group $G=\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ and the finite field F of order p. Then the finite field L of order $p^n$ is the splitting field over F of the polynomial $x^{p^n}-x$. Then L over F is a Galois extension with Galois group G. Moreover, we know that every Galois group of a finite extension of a finite field is cyclic.

Questions
 1. Are my proof ideas correct?
 2. How do we actually find a polynomial p(x) with Galois group $S_n$ for every n?
 3. For problem 2, what if the extension is infinite?

Comment: What do you mean by your third question? You mean if the group $G$ is infinite?

Comment: @TokenToucan If F is a finite field, and L/F is Galois and [L:F]= Infinity, then what could the Galois group of L/F be?

Comment: By Galois theory they are quotients of $\hat\mathbb Z$ by its closed subgroups, and google turns up https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1909140/closed-subgroups-of-hat-mathbbz-cong-prod-p-mathbbz-p-as-subsets for the latter.